# How to implement rewriting in tomcat 7

Tags: java, .htaccess, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have to implement rewriting in my java web applications with tomcat server.

i have to shown this URL in address bar domain:8080/profile/username, in background call the below url
domain:8080/profile?uname=username in my application, Any one have idea about it. please suggest me.

Comment: Use the excellent [URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/).